# Can vcpkg be used in qtcreator with qmake?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, vcpkg

I've searched both the qt documentation and also online but I seems to find only guides or articles for vcpkg for CMake and not any for qmake, so i suspect that it cannot be used with qmake even it's not explicity stated.

I know qmake will not be maintained anymore but I'm working with a project that use it.